# How to properly format a json encoded array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to create a json encoded array that results like this:

```
{
    "properties": [
        {
            "property": "email",
            "value": "testapi@xxxxx.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
$data = array("properties"=>array("property"=>"status", "value"=> "Pending Approval"));   
$data_string = json_encode($data, true); 

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data_string);
echo "</pre>";
```

Which then gives me the results of:

```
{
    "properties":{
        "property":"status",
        "value":"Pending Approval"
    }
}
```

But yet the API then responds back after a curl method that states:

```
Json node is missing child property
```

Why is the child property missing? It's been defined - what am I missing on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are missing an array inside the `properties` key.

```
$data = array(
    "properties" => array(
        array("property" => "status", "value" => "Pending Approval"),
    )
);
//....rest of your code
```

`properties` in json appears to be an array of objects. You were providing a single object, not an array of objects.

Comment: Good catch- I completely missed it. Indeed that was the answer. I will accept it when I can! Thanks.